# cmdline-tools : could not determine SDK root in Appium

Tags: sdk, appium-android

C:\Program Files\Android\tools\bin>sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
Error: Could not determine SDK root.
Error: Either specify it explicitly with --sdk_root= or move this package into its expected location: \cmdline-tools\latest\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install java first in your system: https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp

Then give the jre path in your env variable for JAVA_HOME.